# Can you download a path recursively with httpclient?

Tags: java, httpclient

I was wondering -- is it possible to download a path recursively (like you can do with `wget -r ...`) via httpclient, or a similar Java library? Do I need implement this from scratch, or is there an existing library/crawler that I can use?

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a library which has a direct method for this. But here is my solution:

1) Use [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) to get the links.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href
```

2) Now download all files. If you can use [apache common IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html), then do:

```
 FileUtils.copyURLToFile(URL source, File destination);
```

else

```
byte[] bytes = Jsoup.connect(imgUrl).ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes();
```